# The problem with the kinematics of ik is that the bone moves incorrectly in the animation

Tags: animation

[image]

This photo shows how I moved the bone
[image]

And in this photo you can see what kind of animation turned out. Tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: Your IK constraint has no target designated.  This is not how you make IK.  You need to designate a target for the constraint.